# Eclipse 3.4 Glassfish plugin (server adapter)

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

Since ajax.dev.java.net is down I can't install the Glassfish Server Adapter (Java 5 EE) for Eclipse 3.4 (via the usual way). Does anyone have the plugin.jar and feature.jar archived (or knows where I could get them) so I can install it manually (or knows a download server for Eclipse that has it and works?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you might try the new http://ajax.java.net/eclipse/ site.